# Genesis Framework Child-Theme Shows Blank Blog Page

Tags: wordpress, frameworks

I'm using the "Pretty Young Thing Child Theme" -- a child-theme developed by Studiopress for their Genesis framework for WordPress. Despite going to General Settings -> Reading Settings, setting "Front Page displays" to "A Static page" and defining and setting the Front page option and Posts page option to their relevant pages, the blog page is appearing blank.

All the post are there but the blog page just appears blank.

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

1. Setting "Posts page" to `--- Select ---` (i.e. blank)
2. Creating a page named "Blog" (or whatever you want the blog page to
   be named) and setting its template to "Blog"?

If that doesn't work, I would go to studiopress.com and post on their forum.